# Unable to get dart to output in sublime text 3 even if build successful and without errors

Tags: dart, sublimetext3

I cant get my simple dart code to work after setting up Sublime Text 3 for dart development. I only get the build time, while the print command does not work.

I checked all my configurations, checked if my SDK is properly defined at the right places. I also added the location of the dart-sdk to my `PATH` variable

This is just a simple dart code which I want to run.

```dart
void main(){
    print("Hello World");
}
```

I am using Sublime Text 3, latest version of Dart plugin for ST3 and latest Dart-sdk as well. I can only see:

```
* Running <path>dartprojs.dart
* (output starts below the next line)
==============================================================================
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 255]
[cmd: <cmd data>]
[dir: <project directory>]
[path: <my path variable>]
```

While in all of the tutorials I can see:

```
* Running <path>dartprojs.dart
* (output starts below the next line)
==============================================================================
Hello World
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 255]
```